# Codeigniter file not working on godaddy sever

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tried to host my codeigniter file on godaddy sever but it shows 
**This page isn’t working mydoamin.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**
How to solve this problem, i tried to change .htacccess file but still it shows error. please help me if you can.

My .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Most likely that is an issue on scripting level, so in php. You will have to consult the http servers error log file to find the exact error message. That is _always_ the first location to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

if your project on godaddy in a directory. 
please use  RewriteBase as given below in htaccess

RewriteBase /pass the directory name here in htaccess